# Permissions changes when the pod started running

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have  an application running on the openshift, this application needs to connect to the nfs share . The mounting is complete but the mount point behaves strange. When I start the pod the I could see the permissions on the mount point but after few seconds when the pod is in running state the I see ??? (question marks) in place of permissions.
/nfs/abc is the mount point.

```
Just to be clear with the problem,
Below I have two commands from the same terminal, 
sh-4.2$ cd /nfs/
sh-4.2$ ls -la (The first command I tried immediately after pod creation.)
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  1 root  root    29 Nov 29 08:20 .
drwxr-xr-x.  1 root  root    50 Nov 30 08:19 ..
drwxrwx---. 14 technical technical 8192 Nov 28 19:06 abc
sh-4.2$ ls -la(few seconds later on the same pod terminal)
ls: cannot access abc: Permission denied
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 29 Nov 29 08:20 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 50 Nov 30 08:19 ..
d?????????? ? ?    ?     ?            ? abc
```

my deployment config file is as shown below

```
spec:
      volumes:
        - name: bad-import-file
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-test-pvc
      containers:
        - resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 1Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 512Mi
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          name: abc
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: abc-configmap
                  key: spring.profiles.active
            - name: DB_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: abc-configmap
                  key: db.url
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: abc-configmap
                  key: db.username
            - name: BAD_IMPORT_PATH
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: abc-configmap
                  key: bad.import.path
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: abc-secret
                  key: db.password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - name: bad-import-file
              mountPath: /nfs/abc
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext:
        runAsGroup: 44337
        runAsNonRoot: true
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: havent you tried to fix this with [initcontainers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50878789/9929015) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openshift missing permissions to create a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109707/openshift-missing-permissions-to-create-a-file)